Was the Firebolt attack invented in anime, or does it come from another place?
In Dungeon ni Deai o Motomeru no wa Machigatteiru Darō ka , Bell Cranel has an attack called "Firebolt". So does one character in the anime/manga  Mob kara Hajimaru Tansaku Eiyuutan
Was the Firebolt attack invented in anime, or does it come from another place?

Firebolt is a spell in Dungeons and Dragons, and has been part of the ruleset since DnD 3.5 in 2003. I have no direct evidence that the DnD Firebolt spell inspired the Firebolt spells in the series you listed, but given DnD's influence on the medieval fantasy genre, and the RPG-style mechanics of both series' worlds, I find it very likely that that's where the spell originated.

Unless of course D&D took it from yet another place.  Very possible, but at any rate, not anime original.

I assumed it came from Dungeons and Dragons (I believe other ideas in Fantasy Anime came from it, I think I asked once about it) or Lord of the Rings
